# iTextSharp reader javascript error RSS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pdf, itext

I found yesterday on google iTextSharp for pdf filling data.

but when i trying to read pdf ,i am not getting acrofields from pdf .

Here is code

```
private void ListFieldNames()
    {
        string pdfTemplate = @"E:\Vikas\Projects\PdfWriter\PdfWriter\nbc-app.pdf";


        // create a new PDF reader based on the PDF template document
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
        AcroFields formfields = pdfReader.AcroFields;
        // create and populate a string builder with each of the 
        // field names available in the subject PDF

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, AcroFields.Item> de in formfields.Fields)
        {
            sb.Append(de.Key.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        // Write the string builder's content to the form's textbox
        txtbx.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
        txtbx.Width = 500;
        txtbx.Rows = 40;
        txtbx.Text = sb.ToString();

        //txtbx.SelectionStart = 0;
    }
```

Than i was doing debugging i saw reader.javascript throwing error (error is below )

```
if (typeof(this.ADBE) == "undefined")
   this.ADBE = new Object();
ADBE.LANGUAGE = "ENU";
ADBE.Viewer_string_Title = "Adobe Acrobat";
ADBE.Viewer_string_Update_Desc = "Adobe Interactive Forms Update";
ADBE.Viewer_string_Update_Reader_Desc = "Adobe Reader 7.0.5";
ADBE.Reader_string_Need_New_Version_Msg = "This PDF file requires a newer version of Adobe Reader. Press OK to download the latest version or see your system administrator.";
ADBE.Viewer_Form_string_Reader_601 = "This PDF form requires a newer version of Adobe Reader. Although the form may appear to work properly, some elements may function improperly or may not appear at all. Press OK to initiate an online update or see your system administrator.";
ADBE.Viewer_Form_string_Reader_Older = "This PDF form requires a newer version of Adobe Reader. Although the form may appear to work properly, some elements may function improperly or may not appear at all. Press OK for online download information or see your system administrator.";
ADBE.Viewer_Form_string_Viewer_601 = "This PDF form requires a newer version of Adobe Acrobat. Although the form may appear to work properly, some elements may function improperly or may not appear at all. Press OK to initiate an online update or see your system administrator.";
ADBE.Viewer_Form_string_Viewer_60 = "This PDF form requires a newer version of Adobe Acrobat. Although the form may appear to work properly, some elements may function improperly or may not appear at all. For more information please copy the following URL (CTRL+C on Win, Command-C on Mac) and paste into your browser or see your system administrator.";
ADBE.Viewer_Form_string_Viewer_Older = "This PDF requires a newer version of Acrobat. Copy this URL and paste into your browser or see your sys admin.";
ADBE.Viewer_Form_string_Reader_5x = "This PDF form requires a newer version of Adobe Reader. Without a newer version, the form may be displayed, but it might not work properly. Some form elements might not be visible at all. If an internet connection is available, clicking OK will open your browser to a web page where you can obtain the latest version.";
ADBE.Viewer_Form_string_Reader_6_7x = "This PDF form requires a newer version of Adobe Reader. Without a newer version, the form may be displayed, but it might not work properly. Some form elements might not be visible at all. If an internet connection is available, clicking OK will download and install the latest version.";
ADBE.Viewer_Form_string_Viewer = "This PDF form requires a newer version of Adobe Acrobat. Without a newer version, the form may be displayed, but it might not work properly. Some form elements might not be visible at all. If an internet connection is available, clicking OK will download and install the latest version.";

if (typeof(ADBE.Reader_Value_Asked) == "undefined")
   ADBE.Reader_Value_Asked = false;
if (typeof(ADBE.Viewer_Value_Asked) == "undefined")
   ADBE.Viewer_Value_Asked = false;
if (typeof(ADBE.Reader_Need_Version) == "undefined" || ADBE.Reader_Need_Version < 8.1)
{
   ADBE.Reader_Need_Version = 8.1;
   ADBE.Reader_Value_New_Version_URL = "http://cgi.adobe.com/special/acrobat/update";
   ADBE.SYSINFO = "?p=" + app.platform + "&v=" + app.viewerVersion + "&l=" + app.language + "&c=" + app.viewerType + "&r=" + ADBE.Reader_Need_Version;
}
if (typeof(ADBE.Viewer_Need_Version) == "undefined" || ADBE.Viewer_Need_Version < 8.1)
{
   ADBE.Viewer_Need_Version = 8.1;
   ADBE.Viewer_Value_New_Version_URL = "http://cgi.adobe.com/special/acrobat/update";
   ADBE.SYSINFO = "?p=" + app.platform + "&v=" + app.viewerVersion + "&l=" + app.language + "&c=" + app.viewerType + "&r=" + ADBE.Viewer_Need_Version;
}

if (typeof(xfa_installed) == "undefined" || typeof(xfa_version) == "undefined" || xfa_version < 2.6)
{
   if (app.viewerType == "Reader")
   {
      if (ADBE.Reader_Value_Asked != true)
      {
         if (app.viewerVersion < 8.0)
         {
            if (app.alert(ADBE.Reader_string_Need_New_Version_Msg, 1, 1) == 1)
               this.getURL(ADBE.Reader_Value_New_Version_URL + ADBE.SYSINFO, false);
            ADBE.Reader_Value_Asked = true;
         }
         else if (app.alert(ADBE.Viewer_Form_string_Viewer, 1, 1) == 1)
            app.findComponent({cType:"Plugin", cName:"XFA", cVer:"2.6"});
      }
   }
   else
   {
      if (ADBE.Viewer_Value_Asked != true)
      {
         if (app.viewerVersion < 7.0)
            app.response({cQuestion: ADBE.Viewer_Form_string_Viewer_Older, cDefault: ADBE.Viewer_Value_New_Version_URL + ADBE.SYSINFO, cTitle: ADBE.Viewer_string_Title});
           else if (app.viewerVersion < 8.0)
         {
            if (app.alert(ADBE.Viewer_Form_string_Viewer, 1, 1) == 1)
               app.launchURL(ADBE.Viewer_Value_New_Version_URL + ADBE.SYSINFO, true);
         }
         else if (app.alert(ADBE.Viewer_Form_string_Viewer, 1, 1) == 1)
            app.findComponent({cType:"Plugin", cName:"XFA", cVer:"2.6"});
         ADBE.Viewer_Value_Asked = true;
      }
   }
}
```

how should i fixed this problem ?

Comment: Also: how are you reading the PDF and its AcroFields? Are you sure the PDF has AcroFields (maybe it's an XFA form). All in all, the question is bad. I voted to close it. I'll withdraw my vote if the question is clarified.

Comment: Hi look my question again i added C# code. how should i know PDF has Acrofield or XFA Form ?

Comment: I can supply also pdf if you want.

Comment: I don't understand the second code block with the `ADBE` variable. Is that actually iTextSharp code?

Comment: @Chirs second code block is javascript error that shows when i was doing debugging.